# Why doesn't dplyr have a function combining assignment and piping?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

An extremely common use of piping is to modify a variable. For example,

```
x <- x %>% mutate()
```

It would be nice if there was an operator that both assigned and piped, say

```
x %<% mutate()
```

Is there such a thing and I just don't know about it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way to do this, but not in dplyr.

Pipe is original to the magrittr package, and there is a lot more types of pipe.

The one you are looking for is `%<>%`.

Look at this example:

```
library(magrittr)

iris %<>%
    tibble::as_tibble() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(newCol = "New")
```

[image: Example]

For other pipes, check this link: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html

Comment: With apologies that I believe I'm not supposed to do this...I want to say "thank you" for such a helpful and clear answer.

Comment: You're welcome, dplyr (and others in tidyverse) are great packages. Learn them and your experience with manipulation in R will be easy